# Intercept a basic http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a interceptor to cancel a request with url `/foo`

```
angular.module('moduleApp.config', []).config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('requestInterceptor');
}).factory('requestInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            if(config.url == '/foo') {
                return $q.reject(config);
            }
            return config || $q.when(config);
        }
    }
});
```

But I'm getting a weird error in the console...

> Broken interceptor detected: Config object not supplied in rejection:
> https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar/pull/50

I am passing the `config` in the rejection. What am I missing here??

Comment: are you sure this error occurs int he request interceptor? from what I read it's an error that can happen when the response is not a json  - so it might be possible that the interceptor deosn't reject your request, but lets it happen and afterwards you get the error

Comment: Yes. I just added the code and gives me the error. I added a console log before `return $q.reject(config);` and the url is correct. It blocks the request but this runtime error crashes my app